# How to name dataframe from function input in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a function that creates a dataframe named after the function input
So for example

```
def createfile(filename):
     # the code here to create the df as below 
     filename_1 = pd.DataFrame()
```

but i can't find a way to use the input as part of of the new file

Comment: What kind of file do you want?  CSV?  `filename_1.to_csv(f'{filename}')`

Comment: what did u mean with named dataframe ?

Comment: I think @Sandra John wants to name the variable (not the file) with the parameter of the function. Like passing a string to a function to create a variable named from this string.

Comment: You are right, but i found all comments saying that it's bad thing to do to name variable after function, maybe extracting the file with the needed name is better, thank you all